# Typehinting for filehandle as argument in function

Tags: php

I'm currently investigating some PHP-code and I'm trying to make it more up to date. I found a function, which retrieves a filehandle (via `fopen`).

The returntype is `stream`. I checked it with

```
$handle = fopen("myfile.csv", "r");
var_dump(get_resource_type($handle));
```

As mentioned, the type seems to be `stream`.

When I try to pass this object to a function, I can't force the type with stream.

```
public function parseHandle(stream $handle){}
```

ends up with this error-message:

> Argument 1 passed to parseHandle must be an instance of stream, resource given.

When I try to change the signature to `function parseHandle(resource $resource)` it yields the following error:

> Argument 1 passed to parseHandle must be an instance of resource, resource given

What is the correct datatype and how should I use it in the arguments?

I know I can use `is_resource` in the very first lines of my function to verify it, but I still wonder.

Comment: An alternative solution could be wrapping the code in a helper class. You could pass that class as an argument then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot use the primitive type `resource` as a type hint. The latest type hint system change to PHP, [scalar type hints](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/scalar_type_hints_v5), only added `int`, `float`, `string`, and `bool`.

The error you quote has come up before as confusing, especially in the context of the scalar type hints. Let me template it for you:

> Argument [N] passed to [Function] must be an instance of [Class], [Type] given

The confusion arises because PHP allows classes to have the same name as *documented* primitives (`bool`, `float`, etc.) for all primitives before PHP 7, and for some in PHP 7 and later [<sup>†</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.other-reserved-words.php)
. So when you say `stream $handle`, PHP is expecting `$handle` to be of *class* `stream`. Likewise `resource $handle` expects `$handle` to be of class `resource`.

If you want to type hint resources, I suggest using an `\SplFileObject`:

```
$handle = new \SplFileObject('myfile.csv', 'r');
function parseHandle(\SplFileObject $handle) { ... }
```

This is not the best thing in the world, as \SplFileObject has a few quirks, but at the end of the day, if you want to type hint it in PHP, you must either have an array, a scalar, or a class.

Comment: Is there a RFC for adding `resource` to the allowed types hinting?

Comment: @Xenos To my knowledge, no. Were there one, I would vote yes, unless there was some strenuous technical argument against.

Comment: That would be a bad idea. Instead, PHP should more actively move to convert its core (extensions) to OOP, so that you can use proper (abstract/interface) class names for type hints. The usage of the `\SplFileObject` here abbove is a great example, but I would more prefer to see something like `\Php\Io\Stream` etc.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do type checking for a resource is to do it as the first statement in a function / method.

```
public function close($value)
{
    if (!is_resource($value)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("The argument to this function must be a [blah] resource.");
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

Behold, the SPL Exception: [InvalidArgumentException](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.invalidargumentexception.php).