# Type-hinting for a stream resource (stream_socket_client)

Tags: php, stream, resources, type-hinting, stream-socket-client

I'm looking for a solution to use type hinting on a [`stream_socket_client()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.stream-socket-client.php) resource stream.

Researching this topic, I came across [this question and its accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40637939/typehinting-for-filehandle-as-argument-in-function), which somehow implies that what I'm looking for can't be done without moving away from `stream_socket_client()`, because `stream_socket_client()` returns a `resource` of the type `stream`. And even though `resource` is a primitive type, it's not supported by PHPs scalar type hinting.

However, maybe someone knows how to do this anyway or got an alternative to `stream_socket_client()` that works with type hinting.

Below you find an `Email` class broken down to the most basic code to work with and to give you an idea on how I'm using `stream_socket_client()`.

```
class Email {

    private /* WHAT TYPE HINT TO PUT HERE? */ $_connection = null;

    public function sendEmail() {
        // set email server details
        $smtpServer = // set your smtp server address
        $smtpPort = // set your smtp server port;

        // context options for ssl connection
        $contextOptions = array(
            'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer' => true,
                'verify_peer_name' => true
            )
        );

        $context = stream_context_create($contextOptions);

        // establish connection
        $this->_connection = stream_socket_client("tcp://$smtpServer:$smtpPort", $error_no, $error_str, 20, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context);

        // enable TLS
        stream_socket_enable_crypto($this->_connection, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT)

        /* in the real world, you'd wanna make sure the connection has been established, 
           enabling crypto succeeded and afterwards send the email by writing smtp commands to the stream */
    }
}
```

I'm using PHP 7.4, in case this matters.

Comment: "The special resource type is not an actual data type. It is the storing of a reference to functions and resources external to PHP."  I don't see anything about it being explicitly prohibited like callable but I doubt it would be supported.  Just use `/** @var resource $_connection */` instead.

Comment: See for more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38429595/php-7-and-strict-resource-types